# How to redirect to Home controller from login page?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to redirect an authenticated user (an already logged in user) to a Home controller if/when the login page url is accessed. Here is the scaffold login page

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 {
   //here i want to Redirect to Home controller index method
 }
   else{
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
   }
}
```

how to redirect from the login page to the home index action method? or to a specific controller's action method?

Comment: You don't know how to perform a redirect in ASP.NET MVC Core? Did you research how to do that?

Comment: @mason i have been looking online and trying trying different ways but non of them didn't work, the redirect i'm working on is from the default scaffold login page in _.Net Core 2.1_ with a method signature  `public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null) {...}`  to a normal controller's action method. the usual `RedirectToAction(nameof(Index))` or `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` is not working for me,

Comment: An action method can have return types besides just Task. Look at the appropriate options for you. If you look at the base class for the type that RedirectToAction returns, you can probably figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just this piece of code !

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately this is not working, i'm inside the default scaffold login **Page** i think the usual redirect is not working from page to controller action method. considering without `return` since the login page is a `Task` ... i have updated the code above.

Comment: just changing the return type to `Task<IActionResult>` solves the issue thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Normally it is not redirect to any controller, but redirecting to home view / index.

However you can load an instance (another controller class) and invoke it's method to transfer the action process.

Cheers and Enjoy!